Ошибка: could not load pyinstaller's embedded pkg archive from the executable
у меня есть приложение на Python которое открывает exe файлы вшитые в него. exe файлы добавлены через --add-data, если убрать их из компиляции приложение работает нормально, но с ними получаю ошибку.
параметры pyinstaller:
pyinstaller --add-data "everything.exe:." --add-data "LastActivityView.exe:." --add-data "lock.png:." --add-data "server.png:." --add-data "logo1.ico:." --add-data "ProcessHacker.exe:." --add-data "shellbag.exe:." --add-data "test.exe:." --icon "logo1.ico" --onefile --windowed client.py



добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Попробуйте консоль от админа запуститить, а все файлы в одну папку поместить и добавлять только её.
